# Istio - Cannot handle traffic with nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, minikube, istio

I have two frontend deployments running on minikube with a shift service that returns different versions of the application. I want to control that traffic by using a blue/green deployment with istio; but cannot get it to work, all of the istio rules are ignored and always I'm getting different versions of the application, however I can see on Kiali dashboard that configurations for gateway, destination rule and virtual service are ok.

This is my configuration:

```
# enable istio in dev namespace
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: dev
  labels:
    istio-injection: enabled
---
# shift service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
---
# v1 deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-v1
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: frontend
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
      version: v1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: localhost/frontend:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
# v2 deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-v2
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: frontend
    version: v2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
      version: v2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: localhost/frontend:v2
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
# nginx ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: frontend
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: products.localdev.me
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend
                port:
                  number: 80
---
# istio destination rule
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: frontend
spec:
  host: frontend
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
---
# istio virtual service
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: frontend
spec:
  hosts:
  - products.localdev.me
  gateways:
  - frontend
  http:
  - name: frontend
    route:
    - destination:
        host: frontend
        subset: v1
      weight: 100
---
# istio gateway
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - products.localdev.me
---
```

I have follow several tutorials on this topic, but none of the configurations have worked for me.

These are the tool versions:

Minikube version: v1.28.0

Istio version: 1.16.1

PD: ingress-nginx namespace has istio injection enabled

Comment: Is there any reason you're configuring Nginx ingress and the Istio ingress simultaneously?

Comment: Hello @peterj, thanks for comment!, The reason is that I have other ingress services with configuration for https, request headers and wildcards for request path prefixes and don't want to remove them :(

Comment: I am assuming you are using the ingress gateway external IP (hooked up to the domain hostname `products.localdev.me`)? 

Can you try if it works if you take out the Gateway out of the picture? (i.e. run another pod inside the cluster with sidecar and send a request to frontend service)